# Shapes with 1/4 area of a quadrilatral

Tags: geometry

Given nine points connected as described by the black lines. G the middle of AC, I the middle of ED, and H middle of BF.

By adding segments connecting points in the drawing, create shapes with area 1/4 of the quadrilateral EFDB.
As example - by adding segments EH and DH, two quadrilateral with area 1/2 of EFDB are created: EFDH and EHDB

At least 6 such shapes are known to me

[image]

Comment: Are D and E essentially random or arbitrary points on BC and AB?

Comment: They are arbitrary. EFBD is any quadrilateral. Let us keep it convex.

Comment: For the final answer, do you require one such shape or all six?

Comment: @Brandon_J I'd imagine at least 6, since 2 are given and 2 more are relatively trivial.  (Edit correction:  the example technically isn't a given, whoops)

Comment: @greenturtle3141 goodness, I'm tired - I didn't even see the given ones. Thanks.

Comment: All six. The given are 1/2 the area of the quadrilateral. You need to find at least 6 with 1/4 of the EFBD area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have more...

> **HIFE**
>
>  **DFIH**
>
>  **DHIB**
>
>  **BIHE**
>
>  **HIA**
>
>  **HCI**
>
>
>  So here's the thing... given your choice in actual point locations, either **DHIB** or **BIHE** is going to be a self-intersecting shape.  As drawn in the question, **BIHE** is that shape.  According to [certain math](https://www.techhouse.org/~mdp/midpoint/selfquad.php), that's not a problem, but it doesn't seem acceptable to this puzzle.  That means I'm really at 5 shapes total, and notably I never used point **G**.  I can't think of how to use it either... it is collinear with **HI** which seems to hamper its usefulness.

My attempt as some kind of proof:

> For any triangle, if you draw a line from one of the corners to the midpoint of the edge opposite that corner, you will always bisect the triangle... exactly in half.  So triangle **BFE** is cut perfectly in half when we add line segment **EH**.  That's why adding segments **EH** and **HD** divide **BDFE** in half, because it it really two separate triangles being bisected.  Because point **I** is still a midpoint of **HDFE**, we are able to divide that quadrilateral in half using the same technique, thus making the required 1/4 area.
>
>
>  We can change our order to get the other two "trivial" solutions.  We start with **BDFE**, but this time start by cutting it in half using segments **BI** and **IF**.  The first half, **BDFI**, can be cut in half just like before, which you might expect would add two answers to our list... but it actually gives us a repeat.  We cannot count **HDFI** twice, so we really just have 3.
>
>
>  So here's where it gets weird, you might notice that when we divide **BDFE** into **BDFI** and **BIFE**, we can divide **BDFI** into halves but we cannot divide **BIFE**... except we sort of can.  If you follow the dividing rules, we can make a self-intersecting shape **BIHE**.  The order of letters is important now, so note how the line segments cross themselves.  According to [this math](https://www.techhouse.org/~mdp/midpoint/selfquad.php), which I vaguely remember learning about over a decade ago, the area of a self-intersecting shape is positive OR negative depending on traveling CW versus CCW.  I had to use CAD to check this, but indeed the area checks out if you subtract the small triangle from the big one.
>
>
> [image]
>
>
>  So alternately, instead of that weirdness, you could imagine the points being situated a little different such that **BIHE** is normal looking and **BDFI** becomes the self-intersecting shape.  I don't know why that makes it better, it's just worth noting.
>
>
>  To make the other two answers, I guess I got lucky.  I gathered, intuitively, that segment **HI** was important and thought that maybe connecting it to point A or C might do something useful.  It turned out to be the exact thing I needed and I didn't think about it too hard until now.  I can't for the life of me figure out why it works.  Oh well, it's not like I'm getting massive upvotes anyway.

Comment: Your answer is correct! Do you have a proof for HIA and HCI?

Comment: @Moti I'll try to write up a proof for those tomorrow if I have time.  I'm not sure I'm comfortable with subtractive area being part of the solution though... it kind of defies the meaning of "shape" in a casual setting like this.

Comment: I was just wondering, since there is an elegant short proof - about 4-6 lines. If you enjoy geometry as well as puzzling you might enjoy it. In any case you found 6.

Comment: @Moti well feel free to post it, because mine will not be elegant... I guarantee that.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer. I assume it covers the trivial ones:

> Quadrilaterals EHIF and HIFD are both 1/4 of the quadrilateral EFDB because they are 1/2 of quadrilateral EFDH.

Edited: Here is another one.

> BIHD

Comment: This is 1/3 of the solution. These are not the really challenging ones:)

Comment: I agree - these are the trivial ones.

Comment: There is another trivial and than some more DEMANDING